# How does Emacs compile the regular expressions?

Tags: regular-expressions, compilation

I'm writing code that will have to do a lot of regular expression matching. I understand that a function like `string-match` or `re-search-forward` needs to process its regexp argument given as a string and turn it into a data structure that will be used for the actual matching/searching. This processing is costly and I would like to know if it is done every time I call `re-search-forward` or if it is done only once for each new regexp and is not redone when one uses the same regexp several times.

Let me consider a concrete situation. Assume that I want to loop over all lower-cap letters in a large text buffer. I can loop with a  `(while (re-search-forward rx nil t) ...)` using string `"[a-z]"` as a regexp. Or I can write a loop over buffer positions and test the `(char-after pos)` each time. If the regexp is recompiled with each new call of `re-search-forward` the first option will be much slower than the second one. If the regexp is compiled just once then the first option will be more or less as fast as the second option but it leads to much cleaner code, easier to read and modify, so should be preferred.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Emacs' regexp implementation caches previously used patterns in
compiled form (20 of them, last time I looked). **This is not a detail
you should rely on too much**.

`(while (re-search-forward rx nil t) ...)` is the idiomatic way to
search through a buffer for a regexp, so unless you measure it and
find it to be slower than an alternative, that's what you should use.

Comment: Thanks ! I won't rely too much on this detail but it sure is very satisfying & reassuring to know it.

Comment: @phs This strategy is common in many languages and environments, particularly if they don't provide an explicit way to compile the regexp.